# I want to take a SIGQUIT signal and do some actions

Tags: c, signals

I want to send a `SIGQUIT` to my program via terminal.

First of all what's the `SIGQUIT` signal? <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or something else? And second how can I catch that signal to print some messages
(I am talking about Linux)

Answer (score 0):

`SIGQUIT` is normally used to terminate the process and create a *core dump*.

The default keystroke to send `SIGQUIT` is <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>. You can also send the signal with

```
kill -QUIT <pid>
```

If the PID is negative, uses the positive value as a process group ID, and sends the signal to all the processes in the group.

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> sends a `SIGINT` signal.

Keyboard-generated signals are sent to the entire foreground process group. So if your program forks children, the keyboard signals will be sent to all of them.

If you want your program to do something different with this signal, use the [`signal(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) or [`sigaction(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) function to assign a signal handler function to it.

If you establish the handler before forking, they children will inherit the handler. But if they call `exec` to run a new program, signal handlers revert to the default in that process (since the handler function won't exist in the new program).

Comment: So you detect the signal via these functions right?Cause my problem is that I have used forks in my program so there are tons of child processes so the SIGQUIT signal might happen to one of the childs,so my problem is that i am struggling to send the signal to the parent so he can be able to do the appropriate job

Comment: When you send a signal with a keystroke, it's sent to all the processes in the foreground process group. So it should send the signal the parent and all the children. You can also send to an entire process group by using the negative of the process group leader as the PID with `kill`.

Comment: This thread is a bit old, but it's worth mentioning that if you don't want your child processes receiving SIGQUIT, you can put them in a separate process group.